# Auto refresh controller and view Yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii

How i could make this page auto refresh/update every 10 second when there is/isnt data update. Like Twitter when there is a new tweet.

Example : This is in first second.

> You have 1 name with no status

Then after 10 second, there is an event that "name" data have been added.

> You have 2 names with no status

what should i do? I've tried with javascript, but it wont refresh the data from controller.

this is my actioncheckNames Controller

```
 public function actioncheckNames() {
    //Check Name with No Status
    $noStat = new CDbCriteria();
    $noStat->condition = "status IS NULL";
    $noStat->order = "name ASC";
    $sums = Name::model()->count($noStat);
    //End of Check Function
    return array('sum'=>$sums);
}
```

And this is sort of my index on view.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('name/checkNames'); ?>'
                    , type: 'post'
                    , success: function(data) {
                        if (data) {
                                $("#checkname");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }, 5000 //5 seconds
                            );
                });
    </script>
<div id="checkname">
        <?php
        if ($sum != 0) {
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-block alert-primary fade in">
                <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">X</button>
                <h4 class="alert-titleing">You Have <?php echo $sum ?> Names With No Status. <a href="name/noStatus"><font color="White"><u>Check</u></font></a> </h4>
            </div>

        <?php }
        ?>
    </div>
```

*Update : create actionCheckNames Controller and add ajax script. but my web wont refresh the data.

Comment: can you describe it? or made a sample code?

Comment: Push a message on a Websocket would be the optimal solution, but this is a BIG work.

Comment: I would definately go with websockets but it's not easy to implement. The next choice for me would be a polling with ajax every x seconds.

Comment: Please see my updated sourcode. Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh your page by JS set interval  + AJAX request & can try something like below

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('controller/action');?>'
                ,type: 'post'
                //,data: {var1: val1, var2: val2,....}
                ,success: function(data){
                    if(data){
                        //Refresh your div/html element by appending here...
                    }
                }
            });
        },10000 //10 seconds
    );
});
```